# Eclipse Plugin not working in Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I had developed an eclipse plugin in **eclipse luna**.

It is absolutely working fine as expected in **eclipse luna**.

But now when i am copying this plugin jar to the plugins folder of eclipse juno and restarting my eclipse it is not working.

It doesn't even display the plugin in the installed plugins list.

Also when i am starting the console **(juno)** in osgi view , and typing the command `ss` command my plugin is not listed there.

Is there any version compatibility issue among the eclipse versions ?

## **UPDATE :**

As per Gilbert's suggestion I created the same plugin in eclipse JUNO , and I am able to run it successfully in the runtime workbench.

Now when I am exporting this jar file and manually copying it into my plugins directory it is not working. I ran the `ss` command where the plugin is listed and it is in the `STARTING` state.

Still I am not sure why on exporting the jar it is not working ??

Please help , how to fix this.

Comment: First try starting Eclipse Juno with the -clean option to force the plugin cache to rebuild, just putting things in the plugins directory is not enough. Also look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for messages. There is certainly no guarantee that a plugin developed on one version of Eclipse will work on an older version - it depends what APIs you have used and if they have changed.

Comment: yeah tried with -clean option no luck , also looked at the .log file nothing is there related to plugin loading.

Comment: Also look at the which plugins you plugin depends on and if you have specified the minimum required version. Do all the dependencies exist in Juno? Are the versions OK? This is in the MANIFEST.MF in the 'Require-Bundle' entry

Comment: I am not using the min required version property and corrected the dependencies versions which are available in eclipse juno. But still no luck.

Comment: Generally, you develop Eclipse plug-ins on the oldest version of Eclipse that you want the plug-in to run.  Eclipse plug-ins are sometimes upward compatible.  Eclipse plug-ins are **never** downward compatible.